# Virtual box VM max resolution 1600x1200

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am completely new to virtual machines and just set up a virtual Windows 10 with virtual machine on my ubuntu desktop. The problem is that my monitor is 1920x1080, but the max resolution in the virtual windows is 1600x1200 and all of the other options are 4:3 as well. I set the settings up so that it should have enough juice to run that by far, so i have no idea what's up.

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions? You will have problems if you have not.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?  VirtualBox 6?